# What exactly is each parameter for assembly delegatecall?

Tags: solidity, assembly, delegatecall

I've been searching everywhere but I'm still not clear what each of the parameters are for delegatecall. What I have found is this `delegatecall(g, a, in, insize, out, outsize)`, where `g` is gas and `a` is the address of the contract to delegate but the input I'm not so sure. Is the input supposed to be the signature of the function to be called or just the arguments?

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the [EIP-7: DELEGATECALL](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-7#parameters) and [EVM Opcodes](https://www.evm.codes/#f4)

**gas:** the amount of gas the code may use in order to execute;

**to:** the destination address whose code is to be executed;

**in_offset:** the offset into memory of the input;

> byte offset in the memory in bytes, the calldata of the sub context.

**in_size:** the size of the input in bytes;

> byte size to copy (size of the calldata).

**out_offset:** the offset into memory of the output;

> byte offset in the memory in bytes, where to store the return data of
> the sub context.

**out_size:** the size of the scratch pad for the output.

> byte size to copy (size of the return data).

Comment: but is the input the encoded function signature? and why is the out and out_size usually set to 0?